# Unable to install npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am learning Node js through nodeschool. I install different package but once i upgrade the version of NPM. I am unable to install package. I am getting this error.

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',
npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53',
npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-53-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "scope-chains-closures"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pjain/workspace/Node
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.38
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures
npm ERR! fstream_type Directory
npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures'
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:46:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pjain/workspace/Node/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What's your question? Seems like you don't have permission to access `/usr/lib/node_modules/scope-chains-closures`. Did you try what is suggested in the error message?

Comment: use `sudo` to run as an admin

Comment: check the 14th line in your log: npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Comment: for CodeSchool you are probably using a Linux server in the cloud somewhere. On Mac and Linux boxes, you will need to use sudo frequently to run npm commands, get used to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Try running your npm command as:

```
sudo npm install <package-name>
```